# Get the ID of a sibling after a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, siblings

I use the following code and I would like to be able to get the ID attribute from the `<li>` (the post ID) that is associated with an `<a>` when it is clicked, but I cannot figure out how do do this. Is anybody able to help me at all?

```
<li id="custom_latest_news-5" class="widget custom_widget_latest_news">
    <div class="widget-title">
        <a href="http://test.dynedrewett.com/news-and-events/">Latest news</a>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">
        <ul class="link-list ajax-links">
            <li id="post-5521"><a href="http://mydomain.com/uk-news/last-call-for-self-assessment-tax-forms/">Last call for self-assessment tax forms</a></li>
            <li id="post-5523"><a href="http://mydomain.com/uk-news/young-drivers-gambling-on-no-insurance/">Young drivers gambling on no insurance</a></li>
            <li id="post-5520"><a href="http://mydomain.com/uk-news/tenants-forced-to-abandon-pets/">Tenants forced to abandon pets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is the JS that I currently have -

```
/**
 * Intercept a click for page refresh and run the page refresh JS
 */
$(function(){
    $('.ajax-links').delegate('li a', 'click', function(e){
        /** Prevent the click from doing anything */
        e.preventDefault();

        /** Get the post ID */  
        var post_id = '???';
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need

`var post_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FwqGT/

Comment: Thanks Jason, thats perfect - I was obviously getting my parents and siblings confused.

Comment: Not a problem, @DavidGard.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var post_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

If you need to get the following (sibling) <li>, you could also do:

```
var next_id = $(this).parent().next().attr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks John, but that give me an error (`this.parent is not a function`). I also tried `$(this).parent()`, but that just returned an object. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard. I edited my answer .parent() gives you the whole object. .parent().attr("id"); will give you the id of the element

Answer (score 1):

The li:s with the post ids in your markup are actually not siblings but parents.

This ought to do it:

var post_id = $(this).parent().attr('id'));

Comment: Thaks svjson, Jason below just beat you to the same conclusion, whcih is exactly right.